# Javascript identify file upload complete

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I need a very simple javascript that prints "FILE UPLOAD COMPLETE" when all files have been uploaded. And prints "UPLOADING" if uploading of the files is still uncomplete.

I tried this:

(First of all I apologize if the javascript is very bad. I don't know how to code javascript BUT I would really love to learn the language, just not now because I have other more important things to do. The code below is pieced together from various codes I found online, so pls. correct all the errors you find and post the tips you can suggest to better and/or simplify the code. I actually found javascript coding very similar to PHP except for the different functions used, which I extremely lack knowledge of.)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
function checkStatus() {
    var uFiles = document.getElementById("uploadInput").files
    var pFiles = uFiles.length
    var allFiles = new Array()
    for (a = 0; a < pFiles; a += 1) {
        allFiles[a] = uFiles[a].size;
    }
    for (b = 0; b < pFiles; b += 1) {
        if (totalvalue === 'undefined') {
            var totalvalue = allFiles[b];
        } else {
            var totalvalue = totalvalue + allFiles[b];
        }
        if (b == pFiles) {
            var status = 1;
        }
    }
    if (status != 1) {
        var funccomp = "INCOMPLETE"
    } else {
        var funccomp = "COMPLETE"
    }
    document.getElementById("filestatus").innerHTML = pFiles;
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sample.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880">
    <input id="uploadInput" name="uploadedfile[]" type="file" multiple onchange="checkStatus()"><div id="filestatus"></div>
    <input class="browse_submit" type="submit" value="BROWSE">
    </form>
```

The code above is very wrong. I hope you can tell me what to do. Your comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I’d say it’s possibly over your head to create a multiple file uploader with instant feedback if you don’t know how to code javascript.

Comment: yeah I know. that's why I just want it to just print a simple statement (UPLOAD COMPLETE) if upload is complete. and print a simple word (UPLOADING) if its still uploading. Its the simplest way I could imagine for a progress bar (its more of a progress status.) I was able to get the # of files uploaded. But I couldn't get the size. "var.size" tells me undefined and I don't know how to troubleshoot. @David maybe you can help out?

Comment: Where is your code that sends the file? ie. AJAX or form submit.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen
I used php post to process the form.

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php" method="POST">

Comment: If you do a POST request the browser will load a new page, JavaScript will not get an event, or `onunload` at best. You'll need to look at an AJAX solution if you want to handle the upload in JavaScript. The _upload complete_ can just be the `onreadystatechanged` event of the AJAX request.

Comment: Have you looked at uploadify? It is not best for all situations, but depending on your need can give you a lot of flexibility and control just using the configurations. (http://www.uploadify.com/)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen

So if the user clicks on choose file and then selects for example 3 images and then clicks select I can't use javascript to verify the status of those files if they have finished uploading or not? Because on Chrome, it wont go to the sample.php until it finishes uploading it would just load and wait for the upload to be finish before going to sample.php